# STM32 CAN RX interrupt not triggering

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, can-bus, freertos

I have two STM32L432 nucleos which communicate via CAN.
One STM32 is running FreeRTOS and the other isn't.

The one that isn't can both receive and transmit correctly via CAN.
The one that is running FreeRTOS can only transmit via CAN.
The CAN configuration on the two are identical.

Have tried calling NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig( NVIC_PriorityGroup_4 ); before osKernelInitialize(); is called as stated in https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html however the function isn't recognized so I've changed it to
NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping( NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4 ); which compiles.

So the question is why arren't the CAN RX interrupt triggering on the Nucleo running FreeRTOS?

Nucleo running FreeRTOS:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

#include "gpsdriver.h"
#include "DCMotorDriver.h"
#include "mpu6050_driver.h"
#include "Transmit_driver.h"
#include "partcl_driver.h"
#include "circle_queue.h"

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define PACKAGE_SIZE 8
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan1;

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_rx;

/* Definitions for taskGPS */
osThreadId_t taskGPSHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t taskGPS_attributes = {
  .name = "taskGPS",
  .stack_size = 500 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityNormal,
};
/* Definitions for taskDCMotor */
osThreadId_t taskDCMotorHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t taskDCMotor_attributes = {
  .name = "taskDCMotor",
  .stack_size = 500 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityLow,
};
/* Definitions for taskMpu6050 */
osThreadId_t taskMpu6050Handle;
const osThreadAttr_t taskMpu6050_attributes = {
  .name = "taskMpu6050",
  .stack_size = 500 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityLow,
};
/* Definitions for taskParTcl */
osThreadId_t taskParTclHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t taskParTcl_attributes = {
  .name = "taskParTcl",
  .stack_size = 512 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityLow,
};
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef CanTxHeader;
CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef CanRxHeader;
CAN_FilterTypeDef CanFilter;
struct Queue queueCANRX ={0,0,{0}};
GPS_FIX_DATA data = { 0 };

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
void task_gps(void *argument);
void task_dcmotor(void *argument);
void task_mpu6050(void *argument);
void task_partcl(void *argument);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

void WatchdogHandler(){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(10);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}


// This function is called from the CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler in STM32L4xx_it.c file
void receiveData() {
    uint8_t buffer[PACKAGE_SIZE] = {0};

    while (HAL_CAN_GetRxFifoFillLevel(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0) > 0) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        if (!QueueFull(&queueCANRX)) { // Hvis køen ikke er fuld - Hvis der er en plads til at modtage en besked
            HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &CanRxHeader, buffer); // Modtag beskeden og læg den i buffer
            placeData_1(buffer);
            /*
            for(int i = 0; i < PACKAGE_SIZE; i++){
                EnterQueue(&queueCANRX, buffer[i]); // Læg buffer ind i modtager-queuen
            }*/
        }
    }
}

void placeData_1(uint8_t *p){

}

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */


  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_CAN1_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping( NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4 ); //NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig( NVIC_PriorityGroup_4 );
  //NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping( 0 );
  HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Init scheduler */
  osKernelInitialize();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
  /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
  /* add semaphores, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
  /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
  /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* creation of taskGPS */
  taskGPSHandle = osThreadNew(task_gps, NULL, &taskGPS_attributes);

  /* creation of taskDCMotor */
  taskDCMotorHandle = osThreadNew(task_dcmotor, NULL, &taskDCMotor_attributes);

  /* creation of taskMpu6050 */
  taskMpu6050Handle = osThreadNew(task_mpu6050, NULL, &taskMpu6050_attributes);

  /* creation of taskParTcl */
  taskParTclHandle = osThreadNew(task_partcl, NULL, &taskParTcl_attributes);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
  /* add threads, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_EVENTS */
  /* add events, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_EVENTS */

  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();

  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  gps_init(&huart1, hdma_usart1_rx.Instance);
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 36;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1|RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C1;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
  PeriphClkInit.I2c1ClockSelection = RCC_I2C1CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Enable MSI Auto calibration
  */
  HAL_RCCEx_EnableMSIPLLMode();
}

/**
  * @brief CAN1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 0 */

    uint32_t ext_id = 0x00000000;                            // Den største værdi der kan være på MSB er 1
    uint32_t mask = 0xFFFFFFE0;
    CanFilter.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;            // Vi vælger at bruge mask mode
    CanFilter.FilterIdHigh = (ext_id & 0x1FFFFFFF) >> 13; // (ext_id << 3) >> 16;                        // Da vi har 32 bit ID, er dette de 16 MSB af ID
    CanFilter.FilterIdLow =  (ext_id << 3) | CAN_ID_EXT;    // Da vi har 32 bit ID, er dette de 16 LSB af ID
    CanFilter.FilterMaskIdHigh = (mask & 0x1FFFFFFF) >> 13;// << 5;                    // Maskens 16 MSB
    CanFilter.FilterMaskIdLow = (mask << 3);// << 5 | 0x10;                    // Maskens 16 LSB
    CanFilter.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;        // ID er et 32 bit-tal
    CanFilter.FilterActivation = ENABLE;                    // Vi aktiverer filteret
    CanFilter.FilterBank = 0;                                // Vi vælger filter 0 ud af 14 mulige filtre
    CanFilter.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FILTER_FIFO0;    // Vi vælger FIFO0 til forskel for FIFO1

    CanTxHeader.DLC = PACKAGE_SIZE;                        // Der kommer 8 byte som data i beskeden
    CanTxHeader.ExtId = 0x00000000;                        // 32 bit ID (29 er identifier)
    CanTxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_EXT;                            // Vi har et extended ID = 32 bit til forskel fra standard på 16 bit (11 er identifier)
    CanTxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;                        // Vi sender data
    CanTxHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;                // Der skal IKKE sendes et timestamp med hver besked

  CanRxHeader.DLC = PACKAGE_SIZE;
  CanRxHeader.ExtId = 0x0;
  CanRxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_EXT;
  CanRxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
  CanRxHeader.FilterMatchIndex = 0x00;

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 1 */
  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 18;
  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_7TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_8TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = ENABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 2 */

  while (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &CanFilter) != HAL_OK) {}
  HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan1, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING);
  HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1);

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x10808DD3;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 5000;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD3_GPIO_Port, LD3_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA0 PA1 PA2 PA3
                           PA4 PA5 PA6 PA7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3
                          |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA8 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD3_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD3_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD3_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PH3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI3_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI3_IRQn);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_task_gps */
/**
  * @brief  Function implementing the taskGPS thread.
  * @param  argument: Not used
  * @retval None
  */
/* USER CODE END Header_task_gps */
void task_gps(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */

    gps_init(&huart1, hdma_usart1_rx.Instance);

    /* Infinite loop */
    for (;;) {
        //sendGPS(&hcan1, &CanTxHeader);
        //int8_t result = readGPS(&data);
        osDelay(1000);

    }

    osThreadTerminate(NULL);
  /* USER CODE END 5 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_task_dcmotor */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the taskDCMotor thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/
/* USER CODE END Header_task_dcmotor */
void task_dcmotor(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN task_dcmotor */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END task_dcmotor */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_task_mpu6050 */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the taskMpu6050 thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/
/* USER CODE END Header_task_mpu6050 */
void task_mpu6050(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN task_mpu6050 */
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status = MPU_Init(&hi2c1);
    /* Infinite loop */
    for (;;) {
        float temp = MPU_Read_Temp();
        Axes3 accel = MPU_Read_Accel();
        Axes3 gyro = MPU_Read_Gyro();
        osDelay(900);

    }
  /* USER CODE END task_mpu6050 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_task_partcl */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the taskParTcl thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/
/* USER CODE END Header_task_partcl */
void task_partcl(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN task_partcl */
    partcl_init();

  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      //partcl_update();
    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END task_partcl */
}

 /**
  * @brief  Period elapsed callback in non blocking mode
  * @note   This function is called  when TIM7 interrupt took place, inside
  * HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(). It makes a direct call to HAL_IncTick() to increment
  * a global variable "uwTick" used as application time base.
  * @param  htim : TIM handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 0 */

  /* USER CODE END Callback 0 */
  if (htim->Instance == TIM7) {
    HAL_IncTick();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 1 */

  /* USER CODE END Callback 1 */
}
```

Nucleo NOT running FreeRTOS:

```
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "circle_queue.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

#define PACKAGE_SIZE 8
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
CAN_FilterTypeDef CanFilter;
CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef CanRxHeader;
CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef CanTxHeader;

struct Queue queueCANRX ={0,0,{0}};

//GPS DATA ID'S
uint32_t GPS_ID1 = 0x1;
uint32_t GPS_ID2 = 0x2;
uint32_t GPS_ID3 = 0x3;
uint32_t GPS_ID4 = 0x4;


// Recieved GPS data from CubeSAT
float GPS_LAT = 0.;
char GPS_LAT_DIR = '$';
float GPS_LON = 0.;
char GPS_LON_DIR = '$';
uint8_t GPS_QUALITY = 0;
uint8_t GPS_HOURS = 0;
uint8_t GPS_MINUTES = 0;
uint8_t GPS_SEC = 0;
float GPS_HDOP = 0;
float GPS_ALTITUDE = 0.;
float GPS_H_GEOID = 0;

//Recieved MPU data from CubeSAT
float MPU_ACCELX = 0.;
float MPU_ACCELY = 0.;
float MPU_ACCELZ = 0.;
float MPU_GYROX = 0.;
float MPU_GYROY = 0.;
float MPU_GYROZ = 0.;
float MPU_TEMP = 0.;

//Recieved MOTOR data from CubeSAT
uint8_t MOTOR_DUTYCYCLE = 0;


/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_CAN1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
 // HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  uint8_t sendDataArray[PACKAGE_SIZE] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

  while (1)
  {

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 36;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Enable MSI Auto calibration
  */
  HAL_RCCEx_EnableMSIPLLMode();
}

/**
  * @brief CAN1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 0 */
      uint32_t ext_id = 0x00000000;                         // Den største værdi der kan være på MSB er 1
      uint32_t mask = 0xFFFFFFE0;
      CanFilter.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;         // Vi vælger at bruge mask mode
      CanFilter.FilterIdHigh = (ext_id & 0x1FFFFFFF) >> 13; // (ext_id << 3) >> 16;                     // Da vi har 32 bit ID, er dette de 16 MSB af ID
      CanFilter.FilterIdLow =  (ext_id << 3) | CAN_ID_EXT;  // Da vi har 32 bit ID, er dette de 16 LSB af ID
      CanFilter.FilterMaskIdHigh = (mask & 0x1FFFFFFF) >> 13;// << 5;                   // Maskens 16 MSB
      CanFilter.FilterMaskIdLow = (mask << 3);// << 5 | 0x10;                   // Maskens 16 LSB
      CanFilter.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;        // ID er et 32 bit-tal
      CanFilter.FilterActivation = ENABLE;                  // Vi aktiverer filteret
      CanFilter.FilterBank = 0;                             // Vi vælger filter 0 ud af 14 mulige filtre
      CanFilter.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FILTER_FIFO0;    // Vi vælger FIFO0 til forskel for FIFO1


      CanRxHeader.DLC = PACKAGE_SIZE;
      CanRxHeader.ExtId = 0x0;
      CanRxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_EXT;
      CanRxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
      CanRxHeader.FilterMatchIndex = 0x00;

      CanTxHeader.DLC = PACKAGE_SIZE;                        // Der kommer 8 byte som data i beskeden
      CanTxHeader.ExtId = 0x00000000;                        // 32 bit ID (29 er identifier)
      CanTxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_EXT;                            // Vi har et extended ID = 32 bit til forskel fra standard på 16 bit (11 er identifier)
      CanTxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;                        // Vi sender data
      CanTxHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;                // Der skal IKKE sendes et timestamp med hver besked

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 1 */
      __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 1 */
  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 18;
  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_7TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_8TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = ENABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 2 */

    while (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &CanFilter) != HAL_OK) {}
    HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan1, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING);
    HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1);
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 2 */

}


/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0|LD3_Pin|GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA6 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 LD3_Pin PB7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|LD3_Pin|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB6 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void receiveData() {
    uint8_t buffer[PACKAGE_SIZE] = {0};

    while (HAL_CAN_GetRxFifoFillLevel(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0) > 0) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        if (!QueueFull(&queueCANRX)) { // Hvis køen ikke er fuld - Hvis der er en plads til at modtage en besked
            HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &CanRxHeader, buffer); // Modtag beskeden og læg den i buffer
            placeData_1(buffer);
            /*
            for(int i = 0; i < PACKAGE_SIZE; i++){
                EnterQueue(&queueCANRX, buffer[i]); // Læg buffer ind i modtager-queuen
            }*/
        }
    }
}



void transmitData(struct Queue *Data)
{
    int writePointer = Data -> pointWR;
    int readPointer = Data -> pointRD;
    char str[3] = {0};
    uint8_t tempo = 0;
    int bytesToRead = writePointer - readPointer;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < bytesToRead ; i++){
        if ((i % 255) == 0) HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "___", 3, 100);
        LeaveQueue(Data, &tempo);
        sprintf(str, "%d", tempo);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, &str, strlen(str), 100);
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The only relevant parts is the NVIC setup, the CAN setup and the CAN isr. Maybe your system clock setup if you do it differently between projects. Also, what traffic are you getting on the bus? Actual data or error frames?

Comment: @Lundin. 
When measuring on the bus the sent message appers as expected however the receiver (Nucleo with FreeRTOS) isn't pulling the ACK-bit low.

Comment: But you use the same hardware in both cases, just swap MCU firmware? Or are you using different hardware too?

Comment: Your 2nd example uses `__HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLE();`, the first one doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: @Lundin The hardware is the same and I have tried replacing the Nucleo's if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Lundin I may have deleted it while debugging, however I've tried inserting it which doesn't help

Comment: Then it sounds like the next thing to do is to check both versions against the relevant commit in your version control, and also check the diff between them.

Comment: Okay after a week of trying I tried disabling FreeRTOS in CubeMX and building the project and then enabling it again and building which made it work.

Comment: So it was a (lack of) version control problem after all?